# Optional value in StringTemplate

Tags: templates

I can use a string template like so:

```
st = StringTemplate["a is `a` and b is `b`"];
st @ <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>
```

which gives

```
"a is 1 and b is 2"
```

But I would like the parameter `b` to be optional, so that if I call

```
st @ <|"a" -> 1|>
```

I get simply

```
"a is 1"
```

Something like this is possible with `<* *>`: For the case where `b` must be numeric, I can use

```
StringTemplate["a is `a`<* If[NumericQ[#b],\" and b is \",\"\"]*>`b`"]
```

but is there a way to tell whether a template parameter is present or absent, rather than numeric or otherwise?

Comment: You can use `KeyMemberQ[#,"b"]` to check whether `"b"` is present in the parameters. But I'm not sure `StringTemplate` is really the best option for something like this...

Comment: @LukasLang What else would you use?

Comment: @StephenPowell see the edit in my answer.

Comment: How general it should be? Are there more optional key:value pairs? Do you want the template to care about "a" "b" and potential others?

Comment: @Kuba Where I needed it, there was a single optional parameter, but the general case might be useful for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`MissingQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MissingQ) instead of [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ):

```
template = StringTemplate["a is `a`<* If[!MissingQ[#b],\" and b is \",\"\"]*>`b`"];
```

Then:

```
template @ <|"a"->1|>
template @ <|"a"->1, "b"->2|>
```

> "a is 1"
>
> "a is 1 and b is 2"

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the most direct solution to the question as posed. I hadn't appreciated what is actually happening when the key "b" is missing from the association: `#b` gives `Missing["SlotAbsent","b"]` and then `TextString` applied to that gives an empty string, which is spliced in.

Comment: It looks like the `TemplateExpression` isn't being syntax-colored, both in *Mathematica* and in Markdown/Prettify. Just wondering aloud.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for not using templates:

```
StringRiffle[ KeyValueMap[List]@<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, " and ", " is "]
```

Comment: You inverted the levels of `is` and `and`.

Comment: @Roman O_o thanks :)

Comment: I learn a lot by trying out your solutions. It's like studying a foreign language and learning from the native speakers. Thanks!

Comment: @Roman Thanks for kind words, I learned a lot this way as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
st[sub_] := If[KeyMemberQ[sub, "b"], StringTemplate["a is `a` and b is `b`"], StringTemplate["a is `a`"]]@sub;
st[<|"a" -> 1|>]
st[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>]
```

> "a is 1"
>
> "a is 1 and b is 2"

**ALTERNATIVE:**

Or you could make it more easily scalable for more different cases by defining:

```
strings = {{"a", "a is `a`"}, {"b", " and b is `b`"}};
compose[strings_, sub_] := Block[{st = ""},
  Do[If[KeyMemberQ[sub, element[[1]]], st = st <> element[[2]]];, {element, strings}];
  StringTemplate[st]@sub
]
```

the `strings` variable contains snippets to be added when first element is present. The function `compose` checks all cases and constructs the template

```
compose[strings, <|"a" -> 1|>]
```

> "a is 1"

and

```
compose[strings, <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>]
```

> "a is 1 and b is 2"

just add more entries to `strings` as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

An old-fashioned solution?

```
st2[l_] := 
 l[[1, 1]] <> " is " <> ToString[l[[1, 2]]] <> 
  Table[" and " <> l[[n, 1]] <> " is " <> ToString[l[[n, 2]]], {n, 2, Length[l]}]

st2[{{"a", 1}}]
```

> "a is 1"

```
st2[{{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}}]
```

> "a is 1 and b is 2"

```
st2[{{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"w", 5}, {"x", 10}}]
```

> "a is 1 and b is 2 and w is 5 and x is 10"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation that uses a single `StringTemplate` and no `(* *)`:

```
With[{st = 
   StringTemplate["a is `a` and b is `b`",
      InsertionFunction -> Replace[y : Except[_Missing] :> TextString[y]],
      CombinerFunction -> (StringJoin @@ BlockMap[Replace[{_, _Missing} -> Nothing], #, 2] &)]},
   {st[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>], st[<|"a" -> 1|>]}
]

(* {"a is 1 and b is 2", "a is 1"} *)
```

The `InsertionFunction` makes sure that `Missing["SlotAbsent",_]` is not converted to `""`, and the `CombinerFunction` drops anything that is `_Missing`, *and* the preceding string.